# Panel data, Mixed effect package lme4: random intercept, slope error

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I got stuck in specifying random intercept and random slope model.
The code was:

```
uncond_model_rs <- mutate(marketdata, time =  as.numeric(time)-1)
uncond_model_rs <- lmer(sales ~ 1+ time + (1 + time |shopnumber), data = marketdata)
summary(uncond_model_rs)
```

The error was:

> number of observations (=585) <= number of random effects (=585) for
>   term (1 + time |shopnumber); the random-effects parameters and the
>   residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

my dataset looks like this:

- shopnumber (1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3)
- month (1 2 3 4...12)
- year (2005, 2005,2006...)
- location (uk us ...)
- sales (59763, 43526,46254...)

Anyone happens to know how to solve this?

Comment: The syntax mentioned by the error and the syntax in the model statement you show (`uncond_model_0`) do not seem to be in agreement unless I am missing something.

Comment: Can you post the output to the command $str(marketdata)$ in your question? Also, as pointed out by Erik, it seems that the error message you provided comes from a model which includes a random intercept and a random slope for time. Can you post the syntax for that model?